# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2008 on workgroup network

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, networking, windows-7

Two Windows 7 computers connected through network (workgroup) and can ping each other. I have my database on one of them and need the other computer to connect to this database through my window application.

Here's what I have :

- both pcs are Windows 7 (ultimate & professional).
- I enabled TCP/IP under SQL Configuration Tools.
- I enabled the Browser service.
- I configured the connection string correctly.
- I tried connecting by ip address.
- I created a rule in my Windows Firewall to allow incoming connection yo SQL Server with its default port.
- I don't have another Firewall.
- I allowed external connection from SQL Server Management Studio.

Despite all this, I am still not able to connect to SQL Server on the other computer.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Can you ping the machine or access a network share of it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes I can ping the machine & I can access the network share of it! I can see the shared files and access them through Explorer!

Comment: Do you get an error message when the connection fails? If so what is it.

Comment: It says something like cannot connect to the specified instance name. It's a long message I forgot what it is and I am not in front me the PC now, but it's like when you connect to an instance name that does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a Firewall problem. I disabled Firewall and it worked. Even though I have the port opened as a rule, but there is something else in my Firewall which seem to be blocking the connection.

I ended up disabling Windows Firewall and installing another one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a work group with a PC named SERVER and another PC named CLIENT, you have to choose what security you are going to use.  STANDARD vs NT AUTHENTICATION.

First, did you check to see if the server is active on the default port?

Did you try the following commands on the server from a command shell.

```
cd c:\temp
netstat -a -n -o > netstat.txt
```

**Search for port 1433, is it open and listening?**

Second, did you make sure that TCP/IP is enabled for both the server and native client.  Disable named pipes.  Make sure shared memory is enabled.

[image]

I assume you can connect to the engine logged onto the SERVER via SSMS.  **Correct?**

Comment: Thanks for the tips I will give them a try tomorrow at my desk. NO I am not able to connect through SSMS, what do you think?

Comment: I tried all and it's still not working. Any other suggestions Crafty?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for what its worth, MS has an article on how to configure the ports for SQL server.  It assumes you are using the defaults. For the default instance its 1433, but for a named instance, I do this from the command line:

```
tasklist /svc | find "sql"
```

whatever the PID is for my named instance, plug it into netstat here

```
netstat -ano | find "PID HERE"
```

generally sql server will be listening on 0.0.0.0 which implies ALL adapters/addresses are listening on that port for SQL server. Whatever the port is on that record, that is what needs to be unblocked in the firewall.

here are the instructions from Microsoft which can be used as-is for a default instance, or modified to suit a named instance. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968872

Answer (score 0):

Checking to TCP/IP:
SQL SERVER Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for Protocols for > Click >TCP/IP>Double click TCP/IP> IPAddress > all Enable to “YES” > APPLY> OK